# Update statement in stored procedure is not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sqlyog

I have a stored procedure in Mysql database like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `vboard_75`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_LongWaitCall`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_LongWaitCall`()

BEGIN


    UPDATE cdr SET cdr.CallStatus='DISCONNECTED',cdr.EndTime=NOW() WHERE cdr.CallStatus='RINGINGIN' 
    AND MINUTE(DATEDIFF(cdr.StartTime,NOW())) >=7;

    DECLARE _StatVal FLOAT;
    DECLARE _DevID INT;
    DECLARE Record_Fetch INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE crsr_Board CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  IFNULL(MAX(SECOND(DATEDIFF(CDR.StartTime, IFNULL(CDR.EndTime, NOW())))), 0) AS LRT,vw_Boards_Ext.boardid
    FROM    vw_Boards_Ext RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                boards ON vw_Boards_Ext.boardid = boards.boardid LEFT OUTER JOIN
                CDR ON vw_Boards_Ext.Ext = CDR.DDI AND 
                STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(boards.ResetDate,' ',boards.ResetTime),'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i') < CDR.timestamp
    AND CDR.CallStatus='RINGINGIN'
    GROUP BY vw_Boards_Ext.boardid;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET Record_Fetch = 1;
    OPEN crsr_Board;
    FETCH crsr_Board INTO _StatVal, _DevID;
    WHILE Record_Fetch = 0 DO

        UPDATE stat_values AS sv SET sv.StatValue = _StatVal,sv.timestamp= NOW() 
        WHERE sv.itemId = _DevID AND sv.itemType = 'boards' AND sv.StatId = 3;
        FETCH crsr_Board INTO _StatVal, _DevID;

    END WHILE;
    CLOSE crsr_Board;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE crsr_Board;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Error:

> Query: CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_LongWaitCall`() BEGIN update cdr set cdr.CallStatus='DISCONNECTED',cdr.EndTime=n...
>
> Error Code: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE _StatVal FLOAT;
>       DECLARE _DevID INT;
>       DECLARE Record_Fetch INT DEFAULT 0' at line 8
>
> Execution Time : 0 sec
>   Transfer Time  : 0 sec
>   Total Time     : 0.001 sec

Comment: when i delete update statement then its working fine

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-local-variable.html) documentation refers to having the `DECLARE` statements at the top and also before the creation of any `CURSORS` and `HANDLERS`, which you are following but not at the beginning of the `BEGIN... END` block.

[This](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html) documentation clarifies the question that OP had posted!

It is mandatory to have your declarations at the begin of your `BEGIN... END` block, but not under an `UPDATE` statement.

Additional reference to a similar issue can be found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757441/error-declaring-integer-variable-inside-mysql-stored-function) question, even which refers to the same solution.

Hope this helps!